# How to add cache-control to @RepositoryRestResource

Tags: spring-boot

I have a repository and I need to add HTTP cache headers(cache-control:max-age=12000, eTag:"123".

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "locations")
public interface LocationRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository{
    @Query(value = "from Location WHERE (LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER(:locationName) OR LOWER(alias1) LIKE LOWER(:locationName) OR LOWER(alias2) LIKE LOWER(:locationName)) and active = 1")
    List findByName(@Param("locationName") String locationName,
              @PageableDefault(page = 0, size = 5) Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a filter that will add the header and map it to the URL pattern that you want:

```
public class CacheControlFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=12000, eTag:\"123\"");

            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Somewhere in your configurations:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean cacheControlFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    Filter filter = new CacheControlFilter();
    registration.setFilter(filter);
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/whatever/*");
    return registration;
}
```